# Tensorflow force op execution

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am writing a tensorflow function in Python to implement a generic lag. It has an internal state that must get updated each time the session is run.

Here's a minimal example in the form a simple 1-step lag:

```
def lag(x, name=None):
    with tf.name_scope(name, "lag"):
        zeros = tf.zeros(x.get_shape(), dtype=x.dtype)
        cache = tf.Variable(zeros, name="cache")
        output = tf.Variable(zeros, name="output")
        output = tf.assign(output, cache)
        cache = tf.assign(cache, x)
        return output
```

Let's try it:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [])
my_lag = lag(x)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    result = [sess.run(my_lag, feed_dict={x: i}) for i in range(1, 4)]
    print(result)
```

We get the result `[0, 0, 0]` when what we wanted was `[0, 1, 2]`.

The reason we get this is because the final `cache` op in `lag` is not explicitly used and never gets evaluated. We can force its evaluation by adding a line like this before the `return`:

```
output = tf.tuple([output, cache])[0]
```

And we then get the expected output `[0, 1, 2]`. But this seems quite inelegant. Is there a better way to force an op to get evaluated?

As an additional question, in this implementation we can see that two `Variable`s are used. I couldn't find another solution to make a temporary copy of a tensor, but I don't see why I couldn't do the same with only one `Variable`. Is there another way?

Comment: you could use control dependencies https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/framework.html#control_dependencies